# Multiplication fails in numpy due to wrong shape

Tags: numpy

So I was trying to multiply two tensors (deltasTimesWeights, self.weightedInputs) both of shapes (24,24,3,2), but for some reason numpy thinks that the latter of them is of shape (24,24,3,10). Specifically it gives the error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (24,24,2) into shape (24,24,10)`

```
print(self.weightedInputs.shape , deltasTimesWeights.shape)
            
for index in range(c[2]):

                self.errors[:, :, index, :] = self.activationFuncs[index].prime( 
                         self.weightedInputs[:, :, index, :] ) * deltasTimesWeights[:, :, index, :]
```

Note that self.activationFuncs[index].prime just returns the same tensor shape back. This code is part of a bigger loop in which previous iterations, both tensors were in fact both tensors were (24,24,3,10).

Are there any known reasons why this happens ? Does numpy keep like cache about the shape previously ?

Comment: you don't show the code that supposedly shows the 'reduction' fron 10 to 2.  So we can't help.

Comment: There's no cache.  But it's possible that your previous attempt to change the 10 to 2 did not take.  For example you tried to make the change in-place, not realizing that the modified array was a new object (possibly a `view`).  That's why we need to know the details.  Not the whole code, but the key part(s).

Comment: So the print statements above the loop prints (24,24,3,2) (24,24,3,2) which basically contradicts the error it is giving me.

Comment: are you sure you're not editing deltasTimesWeights in the for loop? Are you modifying a variable that is assigned to the same data as deltasTimesWeights (ie. you didn't copy the tensor).